# list index out of range python decompressing text

Tags: python, list, syntax

The code I currently have is shown below. What it does first is ask the user to input a sentence. The program then finds the position of each word in the sentence and also splits the word into a list to get individual words. The program then gets rid of any repeated words to make the words in the list unique. The program then proceeds to save (using son)the position of words in the sentence (e.g 1,2,3,4,1,1,2,3,5) and unique words to a separate file (which the user can name). The next part of the program tries to decompress the unique text from the separate file and tries to recreate the original sentence from the position of words in the sentence and unique words. I know this stage works as I have tested it separately. However when i run the program now, I keep getting this error message:

File "/Users/Sid/Desktop/Task3New.py", line 70, in OutputDecompressed
        decompression.append(orgwords[i])
    IndexError: list index out of range

I have no idea why this isn't working, anyone care to help? All help appreciated, thanks.

```
import json
import os.path

def InputSentence():
    global sentence
    global words
    sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")
    words = sentence.split(' ')

def Validation():
    if sentence == (""):
        print ("No sentence was inputted. \nPlease input a sentence...")
        Error()

def Uniquewords():
    print ("Words in the sentence: " + str(words))
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[i] not in unilist:
            unilist.append(words[i])
    print ("Unique words: " + str(unilist))

def PosText():
    global find
    global pos
    find = dict((sentence, words.index(sentence)+1) for sentence in          list(words))
    pos = (list(map(lambda sentence: find [sentence], words)))
    return (pos)

def OutputText():
    print ("The positions of the word(s) in the sentence are: " + str(pos))

def SaveFile():
    filename = input("We are now going to save the contents of this program        into a new file. \nWhat would you like to call the new file? ")
    newfile = open((filename)+'.txt', 'w')
    json.dump([unilist, pos], newfile)
    newfile.close


def InputFile():
    global compfilename
    compfilename = input("Please enter an existing compressed file to be  decompressed: ")

def Validation2():
    if compfilename == (""):
        print ("Nothing was entered for the filename. Please re-enter a  valid filename.")
        Error()
    if os.path.exists(filename + ".txt") == False:
        print ("No such file exists. Please enter a valid existing file.")
        Error()

def OutputDecompressed():
    newfile = open((compfilename)+'.txt', 'r')
    saveddata = json.load(newfile)
    orgpos = saveddata[1]
    orgwords = saveddata[0]
    print ("Unique words in the original sentence: " + str(orgwords) +  "\nPosition of words in the sentence: " + str(orgpos))
    decompression = []
    prev = orgpos[0]
    x=0
    #decomposing the index locations
    for cur in range(1,len(orgpos)):
        if (prev == orgpos[cur]): x+= 1
        else:
            orgpos[cur]-=x
            x=0  
        prev = orgpos[cur]
    #Getting the output
    for i in orgpos:
        decompression.append(orgwords[i-1])
    finalsentence = (' '.join(decompression))
    print ("Original sentence from file: " + finalsentence)


def Error():
    MainCompression()


def MainCompression():
    global unilist
    unilist = []
    InputSentence()
    Uniquewords()
    PosText()
    OutputText()
    SaveFile()
    InputFile()
    Validation()
    OutputDecompressed()

MainCompression()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the indices form `words` as indices for `unilist`/`orgwords`.

Let's take a look at the problem:

```
def PosText():
    global find
    global pos
    find = dict((sentence, words.index(sentence)+1) for sentence in          list(words))
    pos = (list(map(lambda sentence: find [sentence], words)))
    return (pos)
```

Here `find` maps every word to its position in the list `words`. (BTW why is the variable that iterates over `words` called `sentence`?) Then, for every word this position is stored in a new list. This process could be expressed in one line: `pos = [words.index(word)+1 for word in words]`

When you now look at `OutputDecompressed`, you see:

```
for i in orgpos:
    decompression.append(orgwords[i-1])
```

Here `orgpos` is `pos` and `orgwords` is the list of unique words. Now every stored index is used to get back the original words, but this is flawed because orgpos contains indices of `words` even though they are used to access `orgwords`.

---

The solution to this problem is to rewrite `PosText` and parts of `OutputDecompressed`:

```
def PosText():
    global pos
    pos = [unilist.index(word)+1 for word in words]
    return pos

def OutputDecompressed():
    newfile = open((compfilename)+'.txt', 'r')
    saveddata = json.load(newfile)
    orgpos = saveddata[1]
    orgwords = saveddata[0]
    print ("Unique words in the original sentence: " + str(orgwords) +  "\nPosition of words in the sentence: " + str(orgpos))
    decompression = []
    # I could not figure out what this middle part was doing, so I left it out
    for i in orgpos:
        decompression.append(orgwords[i-1])
    finalsentence = (' '.join(decompression))
    print ("Original sentence from file: " + finalsentence)
```

---

Some comments on your code:

1. After `InputSentence()` `Validation()` should be called to validate it
2. After `InputFile()` you must call `Validation2()` and not `Validation()`
3. In `Validation2()` it should be `compfilename` and not `filename`
4. You should use parameters instead of global variables. This makes it more clear what the functions are supposed to do. For example `Uniquewords` could accept the list of words and return the list of unique words. It also makes the program much easier to debug by just testing every function one-by-one, which is currently not possible.
5. To make it easier for other Python programmers to read your code you could use the Python coding style specified in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: This would be my way of implementing the functionality of your code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5cc2861b1361791c6e00f21fb342cfae